# Is spectral theorem an equivalence?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

A matrix $A \in K^{n \times n}$ is diagonalizable with orthonormal basis on $K$ if there exists $P \in K^{n \times n}$ orthogonal such that $P^*AP = D$ where $D \in K^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix.

I was asked if the following statement is true or false (**and it is not a homework**):
A matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, diagonalizable with orthonormal basis on $\mathbb R$ is necessarily symmetric.

I think the statement is true because : $A=PDP^T \implies A^T=(P^T)^TD^TP^T=PDP^T=A \implies A$ is symmetric.

But it think this would mean that the spectral theorem is an equivalence and not an implication. The spectral theorem says if A is symmetric, there exists an orthonormal basis of V consisting of eigenvectors of A. This is not an "if and only if".

Comment: Being diagonalizable is an *intrinsic* property, unaffected by a change of basis (which conjugates the matrix representation). Being symmetric is an artifact of the choice of basis.  Just try to conjugate a symmetric matrix in a random way and see what happens: work out some actual *examples*.

Comment: @KCd: being symmetric is also an intrinsic property if you restrict yourself to orthonormal bases (which is what happens when working with inner product spaces).

Comment: @MartinArgerami  good point, I had not noticed the requirement that the matrix is diagonalizable wrt an orthonormal basis rather than some random basis. I suspect the source of the OP's confusion may be not thinking about the difference between "diagonalizable with respect to an orthonomal basis" and "diagonalizable with respect to some basis (not necessarily orthonormal)".

Comment: @KCd: could be.

Comment: The question can be asked this way : if $A$ can be writing as $A=PDP^T$ with P an orthogonal matrix and D a diagonal one, is A symmetric ?

Comment: @John just compute the transpose of $PDP^\top$.

Comment: @KCd isn't what I wrote "$A=PDP^T \implies A^T=(P^T)^TD^TP^T=PDP^T=A \implies A$ is symmetric" ?
The spectral theorem I was given is "A is symmetric $\implies A = PDP^T$ with P orthogonal and $D$ diagonal". Then with the thing I wrote it becomes "A is symmetric $\iff A = PDP^T$ with P orthogonal and $D$ diagonal"

Comment: @John so you've answered your question.  It's not true that real diagonalizable matrices have to be symmetric, but if you specify that the diagonalizable matrix has a basis of eigenvectors satisfying an additional property (being orthonormal) then there is an equivalence.